# PHP, an error on data base method

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am new on php and I have create a project that bring a data from the database as the user selection , and when the execution of the project it occurred an error at an method , and I didn't now how to solve it .
hear is the php code : -

```
     <?php

      $db = new PDO('sqlite:dinner.db');
      $meals = array('breakfast','lunch','dinner');

      if(in_array( $_POST['meal'], $meals)){

     $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT dish,price FROM meals WHERE meal LIKE ?');
     $stmt->execute(array($_POST['meal']));
    $rows = $stmt->fetchAll();

      if(count($rows) == 0){
         print "No dishes available now";
      } else {

          print "<table><tr><th>dish</th><th>price</th></tr>";
          foreach($rows as $row) {
           print "<tr><td>$row[0]</td><td>$row[1]</td></tr>";
      }
          print "</table>";
      }
} else {
   print "Unknown meal";
  }

  ?>
```

and that is the html page code :

```
          <html>
         <head>
         </head>
         <body>

      <form method="post" action="test.php">
      <lable>Select the meal to see all the available dishes:
      <input type="text" name="meal">


      </lable><input type="submit" value="Ok">
     </form>

   </body>
  </html>
```

and that is the output at the browser: - [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3GQFt.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Comment: This error message has been discussed countless times already, so you can easily _research_ it. Besides that, it already tells you what is wrong in plain English.

Answer (score 0):

According to [PHP Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/sqlite3stmt.execute.php) `execute` should NOT have any parameter (void) and it only executes the current query.

You should pass your parameters to fill the query by `bindValue` or `bindParam`. [Look at his example](http://php.net/manual/en/sqlite3.prepare.php) to see the correct way of this manner.

Maybe something like this fixes it, `$meal` has to be only one string and not an array though:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT dish, price FROM meals WHERE meal LIKE ?');
$stmt->bindValue(1, $meal, SQLITE3_TEXT);
```

Answer (score 0):

to pass your params to the query you need to use bindparams not in the execute here how :

```
<?php

  $db = new PDO('sqlite:dinner.db');
  $meals = array('breakfast','lunch','dinner');

  if(in_array( $_POST['meal'], $meals)){

 $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT dish,price FROM meals WHERE meal LIKE ?');
 $stmt->bindParam(1, $_POST['meal']);
 $stmt->execute();
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll();

  if(count($rows) == 0){
     print "No dishes available now";
  } else {

      print "<table><tr><th>dish</th><th>price</th></tr>";
      foreach($rows as $row) {
       print "<tr><td>$row[0]</td><td>$row[1]</td></tr>";
  }
      print "</table>";
  }
} else { print "Unknown meal";}  ?>
```